# What could be preventing wget from connecting to an https site

Tags: linux, ssl

I'm trying to reach an HTTPS site from two different servers. On one server wget works perfectly fine, but on the other it will give an SSL related error. Are there any options that I could supply on the client side to get this working correctly?

Working Wget Version:

```
GNU Wget 1.12 built on linux-gnu.

+digest +ipv6 +nls +ntlm +opie +md5/openssl +https -gnutls +openssl
-iri

Wgetrc:
    /etc/wgetrc (system)
Locale: /usr/share/locale
Compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/etc/wgetrc"
    -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/share/locale" -I. -I../lib -O2 -g -pipe -Wall
    -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector
    --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fno-strict-aliasing
Link: gcc -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions
    -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic
    -fno-strict-aliasing -Wl,-z,relro -lssl -lcrypto
    /usr/lib64/libssl.so /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so -ldl -lrt ftp-opie.o
    openssl.o http-ntlm.o gen-md5.o ../lib/libgnu.a

Copyright © 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Originally written by Hrvoje Nikšić <hniksic@xemacs.org>.
Currently maintained by Micah Cowan <micah@cowan.name>.
Please send bug reports and questions to <bug-wget@gnu.org>.
```

Working Wget Output:

```
wget https://xxx.xxxxx.com/NodeBeanService/NodeBean?wsdl
--2017-03-21 15:12:43--  https://xxx.xxxxx.com/NodeBeanService/NodeBean?wsdl
Resolving xxx.xxxxx.com... xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connecting to xxx.xxxxx.com|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/xml]
Saving to: “NodeBean?wsdl.1”

    [  <=>                                                                                                                                               ] 32,506      89.8K/s   in 0.4s

2017-03-21 15:12:44 (89.8 KB/s) - “NodeBean?wsdl.1” saved [32506]
```

Non-Working Wget Version:

```
GNU Wget 1.11.4

Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Originally written by Hrvoje Niksic <hniksic@xemacs.org>.
Currently maintained by Micah Cowan <micah@cowan.name>.
```

Non-Working Wget Output:

```
wget https://xxx.xxxxx.com/NodeBeanService/NodeBean?wsdl
--2017-03-21 15:04:53--  https://xxx.xxxxx.com/NodeBeanService/NodeBean?wsdl
Resolving xxx.xxxxx.com...xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connecting to xxx.xxxxx.com|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

SSL Connection Info:
[image]

Comment: Those are some old versions. I'm surprised either one handles TLS 1.2, frankly.

Comment: What version of OpenSSL is on each? My guess is the server with the older wget also has an older openssl that can't handle TLSv1.2.

Comment: @DerfK Hello, it looks like the servers are running the following SSL versions: OpenSSL 0.9.8j-fips 07 Jan 2009 (bad server) OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 (good server)

Comment: (@DerfK) `ssl23_method` in 0.9.8 defaults to 'ssl2/upgrade' format hello while 1.0.0+ defaults to 'ssl3+' format, and 1.0.1+ supports TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2. The server apparently won't negotiate with old format, and we can't tell from this info whether it actually permits TLSv1.0 or SSLv3 -- it should not permit the latter if it wants to be secure. Try `--secure-protocol=TLSv1` on the old `wget`

Comment: You can use [testssl](https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh) to determine which protocols and ciphers each server is actually supporting.  You can use `openssl ciphers` on your client to see what ciphers your client supports, then compare the two.

Comment: This won't be the last problem you have with 0.9.8 series of OpenSSL. It's pretty much too old for the modern Internet. Strongly consider upgrading the system (and possibly dumping SuSE).